# iPhone webview autoskips fields on form

Tags: ios, angularjs, forms, webview, skip

I am developing an Webview app for iOS using `angularjs` and when filling a search form with select inputs in iOS it keeps annoyingly auto-skipping to the next field, not letting the user fill the form. Here is the `html` and `js` code:

HTML:

```
<form role='form' ng-submit="submitSearch(models['BuscarEstabelecimentoForm[busca-livre]'])">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group'>
                <input type="text" id="bl-ipt" placeholder="Busca Livre" 
                ng-model="models['BuscarEstabelecimentoForm[nome]']" 
                ng-init="models['BuscarEstabelecimentoForm[nome]']=''" 
                class='form-control' />
                <div class='input-group-addon background-lupa'>
                <a align="center" ng-click="submitSearch(true)"><center ><i class="busca-livre-icon"></i></center></a></div>                    
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <div ng-repeat="select in selectsList">
                <div class="select-style-wrapper-gray" ng-if="select != 'estado' && select != 'cidade' && select != 'bairro' && select != 'estado_civil' && select != 'faixa_etaria'">
                    <select class='form-control' ng-model="models['BuscarEstabelecimentoForm['+select+']']" ng-options="opt as opt.name for opt in selects[select].options" ng-change="change(select);">
                        <!-- <option ng-repeat="option in selects[select].options" value="{{option.value}}">{{option.name}}</option> -->
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="select-style-wrapper-gray" ng-if="select == 'estado_civil' || select == 'faixa_etaria'">
                    <select class='form-control filtros' disabled ng-model="models['BuscarEstabelecimentoForm['+select+']']" ng-options="opt as opt.name for opt in selects[select].options" ng-change="change(select);" style="-webkit-appearance: none;">
                        <!-- <option ng-repeat="option in selects[select].options" value="{{option.value}}">{{option.name}}</option> -->
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="select-style-wrapper" ng-if="select == 'estado' || select == 'cidade'">
                    <select class='form-control' ng-model="models['BuscarEstabelecimentoForm['+select+']']" ng-options="opt as opt.name for opt in selects[select].options" ng-change="change(select);">
                     <option value="" ng-if="false"></option>
                        <!-- <option ng-repeat="option in selects[select].options" value="{{option.value}}">{{option.name}}</option> -->
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="select-style-wrapper-blue" ng-if="select == 'bairro'">
                    <select class='form-control' ng-model="models['BuscarEstabelecimentoForm['+select+']']" ng-options="opt as opt.name for opt in selects[select].options" ng-change="change(select);">
                     <option value="" ng-if="false"></option>
                        <!-- <option ng-repeat="option in selects[select].options" value="{{option.value}}">{{option.name}}</option> -->
                    </select>
                </div>  
            </div>
            <div>
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="buscar" ng-click="submitSearch();">Buscar</button>
            </div>
        </div>              
    </form>
```

Javascript:

```
app.controller('IndexController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$route', '$routeParams', '$http', '$location', 'UserServices', function($scope, $rootScope, $route, $routeParams, $http, $location, UserServices){
console.log('Loading IndexController.');
$rootScope.loginScreen = ' has-navbar-top has-navbar-bottom';
var url =  location.search.split('url=')[1];
var regId = location.search.split('token=')[1];     

if (url == 'verfila') {
    $location.path('/success/'+$routeParams.userId+'/visualizarfila/'+$scope.fila);
} else if (url == 'vermensagens') {
    $location.path('/success/'+$routeParams.userId+'/mensagens');
}

if(regId!='') {
    window.localStorage.setItem('regId',regId);
    console.log('TOKEN:'+window.localStorage.getItem('regId'));
}


$rootScope.reload = function(){
    $route.reload();
}
$scope.selects = {
    'nome': {
        model: 'nome',
        options: [{
            value: '',
            name: ''
        }]
    },
    'estado': {
        model: 'estado',
        options: []
    },
    'cidade': {
        model: 'cidade',
        options: [{
            value: '',
            name: 'CIDADE*'
        }]
    },
    'bairro': {
        model: 'bairro',
        options: [{
            value: '',
            name: 'BAIRRO'
        }]
    },
    'ramo': {
        model: 'ramo',
        options: [{
            value: '',
            name: 'TIPO DE DESTINO'
        }]
    },
    'especialidade': {
        model: 'especialidade',
        options: [{
            value: '',
            name: 'ESPECIALIDADE'
        }]
    },
    'genero': {
        model: 'genero',
        options: [{
            value: '',
            name: 'GÊNERO'
        },
        {
            value: 'feminino',
            name: 'FEMININO'
        },
        {
            value: 'masculino',
            name: 'MASCULINO'
        }]
    },
    'estado_civil': {
        model: 'estado_civil',
        options: [{
            value: '',
            name: 'ESTADO CIVIL'
        },
        {
            value: 'Casado',
            name: 'CASADO(A)'
        },
        {
            value: 'Divorciado',
            name: 'DIVORCIADO(A)'
        },
        {
            value: 'Solteiro',
            name: 'SOLTEIRO(A)'
        },
        {
            value: 'Viuvo',
            name: 'VIUVO(A)'
        },
        {
            value: 'todos',
            name: 'TODOS'
        }]
    },
    'faixa_etaria': {
        model: 'faixa_etaria',
        options: [{
            value: '',
            name: 'FAIXA ETÁRIA'
        },
        {
            value: '18_24',
            name: '18 A 24 ANOS'
        },
        {
            value: '25_34',
            name: '25 A 34 ANOS'
        },
        {
            value: '35_44',
            name: '35 A 44 ANOS'
        },
        {
            value: '45',
            name: '45 ANOS OU MAIS'
        },
        {
            value: 'todos',
            name: 'TODOS'
        }]
    }
};

$scope.selectsList = ['estado', 'cidade', 'bairro', 'ramo', 'especialidade', 'genero', 'estado_civil', 'faixa_etaria'];

$scope.models = {
    'BuscarEstabelecimentoForm[nome]' : undefined,
    'BuscarEstabelecimentoForm[estado]': $scope.selects['estado'].options[0],
    'BuscarEstabelecimentoForm[cidade]': $scope.selects['cidade'].options[0],
    'BuscarEstabelecimentoForm[bairro]': $scope.selects['bairro'].options[0],
    'BuscarEstabelecimentoForm[ramo]': $scope.selects['ramo'].options[0],
    'BuscarEstabelecimentoForm[especialidade]': $scope.selects['especialidade'].options[0],
    'BuscarEstabelecimentoForm[genero]': $scope.selects['genero'].options[0],
    'BuscarEstabelecimentoForm[estado_civil]': $scope.selects['estado_civil'].options[0],
    'BuscarEstabelecimentoForm[faixa_etaria]': $scope.selects['faixa_etaria'].options[0],
    'busca-livre': undefined
};

$http.post(SERVER_ADDRESS+'r=mobile/acessarPerfil', '&mobileKey='+authKey,{
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
}).success(function(data, status, headers, config){
    var profile = data.user;
    var estados = window.localStorage.getItem('estados'),
    ramos = window.localStorage.getItem('ramos');
    $scope.meuBairro = profile.bairro;
    $scope.minhaCidade = profile.cidade;
    $scope.meuEstado = profile.estado;

    if(!(estados == undefined || estados == null)){
        if(JSON.parse(estados)[1].value !=$scope.meuEstado){
            estados = null;
        }
    }
    console.log('Estado: '+$scope.meuEstado);
    console.log('Cidade: '+$scope.minhaCidade);
    console.log('Bairro: '+$scope.meuBairro);

    if(estados === undefined || estados === null){
        console.debug('Setando estados!');
        $rootScope.loading = true;
        $http.post(SERVER_ADDRESS+'r=mobile/listarEstados', '&mobileKey='+authKey, {
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config){
            for(var x in data.estados){
                $scope.selects['estado'].options.push({value: x, name: data.estados[x]});
            }

            $scope.models['BuscarEstabelecimentoForm[estado]'] = $scope.selects['estado'].options[0];

            var meuEstadoIndex = findInSelect($scope.selects['estado'],$scope.meuEstado);
            reorganizeArray($scope.selects['estado'].options,meuEstadoIndex);
            console.log(meuEstadoIndex);

            window.localStorage.setItem('estados', JSON.stringify($scope.selects['estado'].options));
            $rootScope.loading = false;

        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config){
            $rootScope.alerta('Ocorreu um erro ao tentar comunicar a aplicação com nossos servidores. Verifique sua conexão com a internet e tente novamente.', null, 'Boa da Hora');
            $location.path('/');
            $rootScope.loading = false;

        });
    }else{
        console.log('trigger change state');
        $scope.models['BuscarEstabelecimentoForm[estado]'] = '';
        $scope.selects['estado'].options = JSON.parse(estados);
        $scope.models['BuscarEstabelecimentoForm[estado]'] = $scope.selects['estado'].options[0];
    }

    if(ramos === undefined || ramos === null){
        console.debug('Setando ramos !');
        $rootScope.loading = true;
        $http.post(SERVER_ADDRESS+'r=mobile/listarRamos', '', {
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config){
            for(var x in data.ramos){
                $scope.selects['ramo'].options.push({value: data.ramos[x].ramo_id, name: data.ramos[x].ramo_nome});
            }
            window.localStorage.setItem('ramos', JSON.stringify($scope.selects['ramo'].options));
            $scope.models['BuscarEstabelecimentoForm[ramo]'] = $scope.selects['ramo'].options[0];
            $rootScope.loading = false;
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config){
            $rootScope.alerta('Ocorreu um erro ao tentar comunicar a aplicação com nossos servidores. Verifique sua conexão com a internet e tente novamente.', null, 'Boa da Hora');
            $location.path('/');
            $rootScope.loading = false;
        });

    }else{
        $scope.selects['ramo'].options = JSON.parse(ramos);
        $scope.models['BuscarEstabelecimentoForm[ramo]'] = $scope.selects['ramo'].options[0];
    }

}).error(function(data, status, headers, config){
    console.log(data);
});

$scope.change = function(changed){

    if(changed === 'estado') {
        console.log('change state');
        if($scope.models['BuscarEstabelecimentoForm[estado]'].value != 0){
            $rootScope.loading = true;
            $http.post(SERVER_ADDRESS+'r=mobile/listarCidades', '&estado='+$scope.models['BuscarEstabelecimentoForm[estado]'].value + '&mobileKey='+authKey,{
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
            }).success(function(data, status, headers, config){
                $scope.selects['cidade'].options=[{ value: '', name: 'CIDADE*' }];

                for(var x in data.cidades){         
                    $scope.selects['cidade'].options.push({value: x, name: data.cidades[x]});
                }

                if ($scope.models['BuscarEstabelecimentoForm[estado]'].name == $scope.meuEstado) {
                    var minhaCidadeIndex = findInSelect($scope.selects['estado'],$scope.minhaCidade);
                    reorganizeArray($scope.selects['cidade'].options,minhaCidadeIndex);
                }

                $scope.selects['bairro'].options = [{ value: '', name: 'BAIRRO' }];

                console.log('trigger change city');
                $rootScope.loading = false;
                $scope.models['BuscarEstabelecimentoForm[cidade]'] = $scope.selects['cidade'].options[0];
                $scope.models['BuscarEstabelecimentoForm[bairro]'] = $scope.selects['bairro'].options[0];

            }).error(function(data, status,headers, config){
                $rootScope.alerta('Ocorreu um erro ao tentar comunicar a aplicação com nossos servidores. Verifique sua conexão com a internet e tente novamente.', null, 'Boa da Hora');
                $location.path('/');
                $rootScope.loading = false;
            });

        } else if ($scope.models['BuscarEstabelecimentoForm[estado]'].value == 0) {
            $scope.selects['cidade'].options = [{
                value: '',
                name: 'CIDADE*'
            }];

            $scope.selects['bairro'].options = [{
                value: '',
                name: 'BAIRRO'
            }];

            $scope.models['BuscarEstabelecimentoForm[cidade]'] = $scope.selects['cidade'].options[0];
            $scope.models['BuscarEstabelecimentoForm[bairro]'] = $scope.selects['bairro'].options[0];
        }

    } else if(changed === 'cidade') {
        console.log('change city');
        if($scope.models['BuscarEstabelecimentoForm[cidade]'].value != 0){

            $rootScope.loading = true;
            $http.post(SERVER_ADDRESS+'r=mobile/listarBairros', '&cidade='+$scope.models['BuscarEstabelecimentoForm[cidade]'].value,{
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
            }).success(function(data, status, headers, config){
                for(var x in data.bairros){
                    $scope.selects['bairro'].options.push({value: data.bairros[x].bairro, name: data.bairros[x].bairro});
                }

                if ($scope.models['BuscarEstabelecimentoForm[estado]'].name == $scope.meuEstado) {
                    if ($scope.models['BuscarEstabelecimentoForm[cidade]'].name == $scope.minhaCidade) {
                        var meuBairroIndex = findInSelect($scope.selects['bairro'],$scope.meuBairro);
                        reorganizeArray($scope.selects['bairro'].options,meuBairroIndex);
                    }
                }

                $scope.models['BuscarEstabelecimentoForm[bairro]'] = $scope.selects['bairro'].options[0];
                $rootScope.loading = false;
            }).error(function(data, status,headers, config){
                $rootScope.alerta('Ocorreu um erro ao tentar comunicar a aplicação com nossos servidores. Verifique sua conexão com a internet e tente novamente.', null,'Boa da Hora');
                $location.path('/');
                $rootScope.loading = false;
            });

        } else if($scope.models['BuscarEstabelecimentoForm[cidade]'].value == 0) {
            $scope.selects['bairro'].options = [{
                value: '',
                name: 'BAIRRO'
            }];
            $scope.models['BuscarEstabelecimentoForm[bairro]'] = $scope.selects['bairro'].options[0];
        }

    } else if(changed === 'ramo') {
        if($scope.models['BuscarEstabelecimentoForm[ramo]'].value != 0){

            $scope.selects['especialidade'].options = [{
                value: '',
                name: 'ESPECIALIDADE'
            }];
            $rootScope.loading = true;
            console.log($scope.models['BuscarEstabelecimentoForm[ramo]']);
            $http.post(SERVER_ADDRESS+'r=mobile/listarEspecialidades', '&ramo='+$scope.models['BuscarEstabelecimentoForm[ramo]'].value,{
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
            }).success(function(data, status, headers, config){
                for(var x in data.especialidades){
                    $scope.selects['especialidade'].options.push({value: x, name: data.especialidades[x].especialidade_nome});
                }
                $scope.models['BuscarEstabelecimentoForm[especialidade]'] = $scope.selects['especialidade'].options[0];
                $rootScope.loading = false;
            }).error(function(data, status,headers, config){
                $rootScope.alerta('Ocorreu um erro ao tentar comunicar a aplicação com nossos servidores. Verifique sua conexão com a internet e tente novamente.', null,'Boa da Hora');
                $location.path('/');
                $rootScope.loading = false;
            });
        } else if($scope.models['BuscarEstabelecimentoForm[ramo]'].value == 0) {
            $scope.selects['especialidade'].options = [{
                value: '',
                name: 'ESPECIALIDADE'
            }];

            $scope.models['BuscarEstabelecimentoForm[especialidade]'] = $scope.selects['especialidade'].options[0];
        }
    } else if(changed === 'genero'){
        if($scope.models['BuscarEstabelecimentoForm[genero]'].value != 0){
            document.getElementsByClassName('filtros')[0].disabled = false;
            document.getElementsByClassName('filtros')[1].disabled = false;
        } else {
            document.getElementsByClassName('filtros')[0].disabled = true;
            document.getElementsByClassName('filtros')[1].disabled = true;
            $scope.models['BuscarEstabelecimentoForm[estado_civil]'] = $scope.selects['estado_civil'].options[0];
            $scope.models['BuscarEstabelecimentoForm[faixa_etaria]'] = $scope.selects['faixa_etaria'].options[0];
        }           
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's been a long time ago, but I was able to solve it by editing the bootstrap file. I know it's not ok to do this, but it seemed to be the only way to solve it. I am not sure if this is a bootstrap bug, since this was the first time I experienced something like that.